# Toggling disabled attribute

Tags: jquery, performance

I am looking for a way to clean/condense/improve the performance of my current snippet: `input` & `output` are already defined variables.

```
if (input.val().length <= 0) {
    output.attr('disabled', true);
} else {
    output.attr('disabled', false);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you can use the boolean expression directly:

```
output.attr('disabled', input.val().length <= 0);
```

[Gratuitous Live Example](http://jsbin.com/uzutaq/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/uzutaq/1/edit)

Answer (score 1):

You should be using `prop` over `attr`. See here http://api.jquery.com/prop/

```
output.prop('disabled', (input.val().length <= 0));
```

Comment: It doesn't matter, the jQuery team *immediately* backed off making `attr` only work on attributes as soon as 1.6 came out. (And of course, `disabled` **is** an attribute, through if we were being very strict, we wouldn't use `true` and `false` with it.) `attr` works just fine for `disabled` and that's not likely to change.

Answer (score 0):

```
output.attr('disabled', (input.val().length <= 0));
```